# Compass 1.0 doesn't use all prefixes for Flexbox

Tags: css, sass, prefix, flexbox, compass-sass

I use Compass 1.0 and when I do `@include display-flex;` or any other flex related property I get only

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

etc. No `-moz` or `-o` prefixes. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera has *never* used the `-o-` prefix for Flexbox.  It was introduced under the Presto engine without prefixes.  It wasn't until later that support for Flexbox properties (along with a few others) that the `-webkit-` prefix was also supported.

The Flexbox module that currently appears in the 1.0 alphas *only* emits the properties for the current Flexbox specification.  Because of this, you won't be seeing the `-moz-` prefix either: the Mozilla engine only uses prefixes for the original Flexbox specification (eg. `display: -moz-box`).  Mozilla supports the current specification without prefixes from 22.0 onwards (though support for flex-wrap didn't exist until 28.0).  You also won't see the `-ms-`prefix because the IE versions that use prefixes support the older March 2012 draft (eg. `display: -ms-flexbox`).

Now, if you are interested in a set of mixins that are compatible with Compass that will cover all of your bases, I have written a few:

- [Compatible with Compass 1.0](https://github.com/cimmanon/translucencss/blob/master/stylesheets/translucencss/css3/_flexbox.scss) ([slightly older version that shows usage](https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/6b646b9b0ad8212da3c2))
- [Compatible with Compass 0.12](https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/4461470) ([try it out on CodePen](http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/xKChl))

Comment: Very useful script. I just dropped it in, recompiled, and it Just Worked. I now have flexbox working on IE10 within 5 minutes.  Thank you very much @cimmanon.