# Compass-core box mixin undefined

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am trying to use flexbox prefix.  When using compass-core box mixin, with

```
@include display-box;`
```

or any other box mixins, it gives:

```
Undefined mixin 'display-box'
```

However, if I do

```
@include opacity (1);
@include border-radius;
```

No compilation error.

Compass version:

```
compass (1.0.0.alpha.19, 0.12.6)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-import-once (1.0.4)
```

What did I miss out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compass beta doesn't use all prefixes for flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530430/compass-beta-doesnt-use-all-prefixes-for-flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. After having a look at the `compass-1.0.0.alpha.21` code I noticed the line `@warn "The compass/css3/box module is DEPRECATED and will be removed in the next release. Please use compass/css3/flexbox instead.";` I then wondered why the box module is then still listed in the official docs. Bottomline: The default documentation resource on the Compass website only covers the outdated release version 0.12.2, whereas we've been using the latest (still unreleased) dev version 1.x. There is another doc version at: http://beta.compass-style.org/reference/compass/. (Notice the "beta" subdomain!)